# Add public property to a css file

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to configure some custom properties in my web component. These property corresponds to css attributes like background color etc.

I am having difficulty in adding these attributes to my dom. I tried

@tagColor is my property in targetConfig

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('topnews-item-article-keywords').add("background", '$tagColor');
```

Also i tried calling a like below

```
<span style={headerColorToDisplay}>{top.header}&nbsp;</span>

get headerColorToDisplay () {
    return 'background:$tagColor'
}
```

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't use `$` to access the variable's value in Javascript. We use `this` keyword.

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class MyColorDemo extends LightningElement {
    @api tagColor= "blue"; //This will be override from the value you pass from app builder target

    get headerColorToDisplay(){
        return "color:"+this.tagColor;
    }

}
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_accessibility_attributes

Comment: Thanks. I did not read fully, hoping its passed as $property name jiust like in wire methods with params!